# regular expression matching url

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match the fragment portion of a url, meaning a sub-string that begins with '#'.

A URL should *not* have a fragment and a query. So, if a '?' precedes the first '#', the sub-string "#..." should not match.

**example of url(s) with fragment:**

`http://exampleurl.com:8080/#this?whole#thing?is#a?fragment`

`http://exampleurl.com:8080#this?whole#thing?is#a?fragment`

`http://exampleurl.com#this?whole#thing?is#a?fragment`

**example of url with no fragment:**

`http://exampleurl.com:8080/?#this?whole#thing?is#NOT?a#fragment`

`http://exampleurl.com:8080/?this?whole#thing?is#NOT?a#fragment`

The regular expression should match `"#this?whole#thing?is#a?fragment"` in the first example, but should not match anything in the second example. As stated before, if there is a '?' preceding the first '#', then it will be considered a query and not a fragment.

**attempt:**

```
"#+.+$"
```

The above regex matches correctly in regards to the first example, but it will also match the sub-string `"#thing?is#NOT?a#fragment"` in the second example which is not desirable. I am not sure how to put in the proper guards to prevent it from matching with a sub-string that has a '?' preceding it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one matched all your cases correctly. Result is in first group.

```
/^[^#?]*(#.*)/gm
```

check results here https://regex101.com/r/p6tsh2/1